# Prove that the set of skew-symmetric matrices is closed under addition

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, skew-symmetric-matrices

I am trying to prove that W is a subspace of V with:

$V = M_{n\times n}$,
$W = \{A \in M_{n\times n} : A = -A^T\}$

I am fairly sure $W$ is closed under addition, but am not sure how to prove it for all $M_{n\times n}$

I can prove it for $M_{2\times 2}$:

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a\\-a & 0\end{bmatrix} \in W$

Let $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & b\\-b & 0\end{bmatrix} \in W$

$A + B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a\\-a & 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0 & b\\-b & 0\end{bmatrix}$
$ = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a + b\\-a-b & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a + b\\-(a+b) & 0\end{bmatrix} \in W$

How could I generalise this to all $A, B \in M_{n\times n}$

Comment: Let $L: M_{n\times n} \to M_{n\times n}$ be defined by $L(A) = A+A^T$. It is easy to check that $L$ is linear, hence $\ker L $ is a subspace.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix

Comment: This set of matrices is a Lie algebra under addtion, the bracket $ [A, B]= AB-BA $ and multiplication by scalars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A,B\in W$. Then
$$-(A+B)^T=-(A^T+B^T)=-A^T-B^T=A+B$$
The final equality comes from $A=-A^T$ and $B=-B^T$ (because they are in $W$). So $A+B=-(A+B)^T$ so $A+B\in W$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it like an upper triangle matrix with zero diagonal elements, the set of which is quite obviously closed under addition for a given size $n$. The elements below the main diagonal is fully determinable from the elements above it.